# Angular $watch does not fire any event in my directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

i try to update an elements content depending on the attribute value of my custom directive. the code below performs well but only once on site-load. dynamic updates on the attribute value do not fire any event. what do i do wrong?

markup inside ng-repeat (match in matches):

```
<div ng-tipp-result="[[getIconClass(match)]]"></div>
```

directive:

```
myApp.directive('ngTippResult', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            var content = "s";

            scope.$watch(attrs.ngTippResult, function(v){
                switch(v){
                    case 1: content = '<i class="icon-circle"></i>';break;
                    case 2: content = '<i class="icon-X"></i>';break;
                    case 3: content = '<i class="icon-Y"></i>';break;
                    case 4: content = '<i class="icon-Z"></i>';break;
                    case 5: content = '<i class="icon-ok"></i>';break;
                    case 6: content = '<i class="icon-minus"></i>';break;
                }

                elem.html(content);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

**Edit:**

using the attributes name as string solved the problem but caused another, i ran into a infinit digest loop with the code above.

```
<li ng-repeat="match in matches">
    <i class="pull-right [[getIconClass(match)]]"></i>
</li>
```

getIconClass is a controller method which returns values from 1 to 6 depending on match.

Answer (score 3):

The first parameter to `$watch` should be a getter function for the value you want to watch.  Try

```
scope.$watch(function(){return attrs.ngTippResult}, function(v){...});
```

See the docs [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope#methods_$watch).

What's probably happening is that `attrs.ngTippResult` is evaluating to a String.  A String is a valid input, but I don't think that's what you intended; it seems like you want an update everytime `attrs.ngTippResult` changes.  Instead, your current code is watching the property on the scope with the value of attrs.ngTippResult (for example, if attrs.ngTippResult was `"fish"`, the value you would be watching with your current code would actually be `$scope.fish`, which probably isn't what you want.

**EDIT**

Also, aaronfrost's answer might be the best for what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

You can map the attribute to your directive scope:

`myApp.directive('ngTippResult', function() {
    return {
scope: { theTippResult:"=ngTippResult", ...}}});`

then you'll just need to put the variable name in a string:
`scope.$watch('theTippResult', function(v){...});`

--Or-- use the function method like Hylianpuffball suggested, though I'd still map it to your model just as 'self documenting' code.

Answer (score 1):

For the attrs object in the directive, you should not use scope.$watch. You should use attrs.$observe. It was built to allow you to watch the attribute values, without doing a watch. However, the syntax is almost identical.

See the [doc here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24compile.directive.Attributes)