# AngularJS trigger and watch object value change in service from controller

Tags: angularjs, watch

I'm trying to watch for changes in a service from a controller.  I tried various things based on many qns here on stackoverflow, but I've been unable to make it work.

html:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <div ng-click="setFTag()">Click Me</div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

javascript:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.service('myService', function() {
    this.tags = {
        a: true,
        b: true
    };


    this.setFalseTag = function() {
        alert("Within myService->setFalseTag");
        this.tags.a = false;
        this.tags.b = false;

        //how do I get the watch in MyCtrl to be triggered?
    };
});


myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, myService) {

    $scope.setFTag = function() {
        alert("Within MyCtrl->setFTag");
        myService.setFalseTag();
    };        

    $scope.$watch(myService.tags, function(newVal, oldVal) {
        alert("Inside watch");
        console.log(newVal);
        console.log(oldVal);
    }, true);

});
```

How do I get the watch to trigger in the Controller?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sathishvj/b3A8B/3/)

Comment: See my answer in the question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20623715/angular-watch-does-not-any-fire-event-in-my-directive/20623766#20623766).  Your syntax in your `watch` function isn't what you want, but it's still valid angular syntax, which is why you're not getting a log error.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Try to write `$watch` by this way:

```
myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, myService) {


    $scope.setFTag = function() {
       myService.setFalseTag();
    };        

    $scope.$watch(function () {
       return myService.tags;
     },                       
      function(newVal, oldVal) {
        /*...*/
    }, true);

});
```

Demo <kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b3A8B/5/)**</kbd>

**[EDIT]**

Sometimes this way will not work especially if service has been updated from 3d party.

To make it work we must *help* to angular to fire digest cycle.

Here is an example:

On service side when we want update `tags` value write something like:

```
if($rootScope.$root.$$phase != '$apply' && $rootScope.$root.$$phase != '$digest'){
   $rootScope.$apply(function() {
     self.tags = true;
   });
 }
 else {
   self.tags = true;
  }
```

Comment: I had no idea you could use watch in this way. This is a game changer. So much win.

Comment: for me this way is better because you avoid spelling mistakes with variables.

Comment: @Phill I only added other test case:  if you use for example Cordova plugin thats out of angular scope, the watcher doesn't work. People might copy/paste this example and will be surprised why it doesn't work. So I try to cover different cases

Comment: Can you explain a little bit why we have to use the return function? It worked perfectly but I don't really get it.

Comment: Why is there no `return` statement in the service? How does that work?

Comment: I had to use $rootScope.$apply to trigger a watched variable inside my controller after it is being changed inside a directive.