# Controller triggered via factory

Tags: angularjs

I am still a novice with angular. I have asked a question similar to this before, but it seems to be a different issue at work here.

I have two controllers and a factory sharing information between them. I have two separate divs using two different controllers to show / hide using ng=show;

HTML

```
<div id=main>
  <div ng-controller="Ctrl1">
    <div ng-show="var1">Hidden Stuff</div>
  </div>
  <div ng-controller="Ctrl2">
    <div ng-show="var1">More Hidden Stuff</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Both use the same var for ng-show, shared by a factory

JS Factory

```
app.factory('Srvc', function($rootScope) {
    var Srvc = {};
        Srvc.var1;
    return Srvc;
});
```

JS Controllers

```
app.controller('Ctrl1', function($scope, Srvc) {
    $scope.var1 = false;
    if (user interacts with html in div with ng-controller="Ctrl1") {
        $scope.var1 = true;
        Srve.var1 = $scope.var1;
    }
});

app.controller('Ctrl2', function($scope, Srvc) {
    $scope.var1 = Srvc.var1;
    if ($scope.var1 === true) {
        update HTML in div with ng-controller="Ctrl2" 
        although I shouldn't need to do this really should I?
    }
});
```

So from what I can tell the factory works ok, the data is saved in the factory Srvc.var1. However when I pass the data `true` to `Srvc.var1` I cannot seem to get `Ctrl2` to 'trigger' and update its html with `ng-show=true`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve this problem without explicitly creating a watcher, is to wrap `var1` in an object inside the service and then pass this object as a `$scope` variable for both `Ctrl1` and `Ctrl2` controllers.

**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/2bCxPa12osLy88RiL4sg?p=preview)**

***Javascript***

```
  .factory('Svc', function() {
    var service = {
      data: {}
    };

    // If you perform http requests or async procedures then set data.var1 here
    service.data.var1 = true;

    return service;
  })

  .controller('Ctrl1', function($scope, Svc) {
    $scope.data = Svc.data;
  })

  .controller('Ctrl2', function($scope, Svc) {
    $scope.data = Svc.data;
  });
```

***HTML***

```
<div id="main">
  <div ng-controller="Ctrl1">
    <div ng-show="data.var1">Hidden Stuff</div>
    <button type="button" ng-click="data.var1 = true">Set data.var1 to true</button>
    <button type="button" ng-click="data.var1 = false">Set data.var1 to false</button>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div ng-controller="Ctrl2">
    <div ng-show="data.var1">More Hidden Stuff</div>
    <button type="button" ng-click="data.var1 = true">Set data.var1 to true</button>
    <button type="button" ng-click="data.var1 = false">Set data.var1 to false</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

So it seems I need to `$watch` the service for a change within the controller.

Original answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20667474/angularjs-trigger-and-watch-object-value-change-in-service-from-controller).

```
app.controller('Ctrl2', function($scope, Srvc) {
    $scope.$watch(function () {
       return Srvc.var1;
     },                       
      function(newVal, oldVal) {
          $scope.var1 = newVal;
    }, true);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think setting Var1 to $rootScope instead of Srvc should work, just call $scope.$root.$digest() after updating var1.

and use ng-show=$root.Var1 in view.

Comment: I have read that using global vars in angular can lead to unexpected consequences

Comment: if you don't know what you are doing yes. because the global variable can get updated.

Comment: "if you don't know what you are doing" - I fall straight into this category)