# AngularJS trigger and watch object value change in service from controller from another module (Extended)

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Referring to this question
[AngularJS trigger and watch object value change in service from controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20667474/angularjs-trigger-and-watch-object-value-change-in-service-from-controller)

It is trying to watch for changes in a service from a controller. 
Im trying to extend it to handle multiple module (concurrent app in same page's different div's) communication.

**Problem:**

I want to achieve the similar feat, but with slight different scenario. I have two modules myApp and yourApp for example. myApp has a service. I want to watch changes in myApp's service within yourApp module's controller. Can it be done? or is there different method to reflect and detect data changes of one module inside another module.

Consider the example code below:

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <div ng-click="setFTag()">Click Me</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div ng-app="yourApp">
    <div ng-controller="yourCtrl">       
    </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
// myApp module
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

// myApp's service
myApp.service('myService', function() {
    this.tags = {
        a: true,
        b: true
    };

    this.setFalseTag = function() {
        alert("Within myService->setFalseTag");
        this.tags.a = false;
        this.tags.b = false;

    //how do I get the watch in YourCtrl of yourApp module to be triggered?
    };
});

// myApp's controller
myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, myService) {

    //$scope.myService = myService;    
    $scope.setFTag = function() {
        alert("Within MyCtrl->setFTag");
        myService.setFalseTag();
    };        

    /*
    $scope.$watch(function () {
        return myService.tags;
    }, function(newVal, oldVal) {
        alert("Inside watch");
        console.log(newVal);
        console.log(oldVal);
    }, true);  
    */
});

// yourApp module (Injecting myApp module into yourApp module)
var yourApp = angular.module('yourApp',['myApp']);
// yourApp's controller
yourApp.controller('YourCtrl', function($scope, myService) {

    $scope.$watch(function () {
        return myService.tags;
    }, function(newVal, oldVal) {
        alert("Inside watch of yourcontroller");
        console.log(newVal);
        console.log(oldVal);
    }, true);

});
```

**Note: I am not sure if this is the right way to communicate between modules. Any suggestion or the solution will be highly appreciated.**

**P.S. Ive bootstrapped two modules to fit into same page.**

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sanjaykhadka/b3A8B/173/)

Comment: Why do you need multiple apps? I don't think you can communicate between them.

Comment: You have a typo in your fiddle. `yourCtrl` is not defined - `YourCtrl` on the other hand, is.

Comment: @KasperLewau Updated the fiddle for the typo. Thanx for pointing out.

Answer (score 1):

Communicating between modules is a whole different story from communicating between apps.

In the case of communicating between *modules*, it's only a matter of injecting module A into module B.

In which case, module B has complete access to inject/communicate with *anything* exposed in module A.

---

Communicating between *apps* however, is somewhat more complicated. You would need to setup something 'outside' the angular world, accepting properties from both applications.

I've put together a [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/lomakipiko/1/edit?html,js,output), showcasing *how* you can do it.

With that said, I'm not sure I would recommend it - but then again best practices on the subject do not exist afaik.

The gist of it is;

1. Setup a *new instance* of a shared service that lives *outside* the Angular world.
2. Attach the instance of said service to `window`.
3. Access the above instance in your app specific services/controllers through `$window`.
4. Register *each* $scope that needs to access the data stored in the shared service.
5. Upon updating data in the shared service, *loop through* the registered $scopes and trigger an `$evalAsync`(so as to not end up with  `$digest already in progress`).
6. Watch as your data is synced across applications.

---

This is just a PoC on how to do it, I would not recommend it as it sort of *blows* when it comes to unit testing. And also because we are exposing properties on `window`. **yuck.**

Sure, you could disregard from exposing on `window` - but then your code would have to live in the same file (*afaic*). Yet another, **yuck.**

---

To build upon this, if you were to decide (or, be able to) only use a single `app` (multiple modules is just fine) and want to communicate/sync a service with multiple components I reckon this would be the best way to do so:

```
app.service('shared', function () {
  var data = {
      a: true,
      b: true
  };

  this.toggle = function() {
    data.a = !data.a;
    data.b = !data.b;
  };

  Object.defineProperty(this, 'data', {
      get: function () {
          return data;
      }
  });      
});
```

By using an object `getter`, you won't need to setup a `$watch` to sync data across your components within the same module. Nor trigger manual `$digest`'s.

[another jsbin](http://jsbin.com/vasapofula/1/edit?html,js,output) - showcasing the above.

---

The difference between *two modules* and *two apps* as I see it:

**2 modules**

Two separate modules that gets 'bundled' together into a single application (either by a third module, or injecting module A into B).

```
var app1 = angular.module('app1', ['app2', 'app3']);

var app2 = angular.module('app2', []);

var app3 = angular.module('app3', []);

angular.bootstrap(/*domElement*/, app1);
```

---

**2 Apps**

```
var app1 = angular.module('app1', []);
var app2 = angular.module('app2', []);

angular.bootstrap(/*domElement1*/, app1);
angular.bootstrap(/*domElement2*/, app2);
```

I don't think there is *any point* in having two applications and share `state` between the two. I think the whole point with running two applications is to separate the two. Otherwise it's just over engineering *imho*.

Some thoughts:

- You could add a common dependency to both applications. It probably wont be a shared state, but you would have access to the same implementation in both apps.
- You could *possibly* utilise `sessionStorage` as a medium of transportation for your data between the two applications. Just make sure to cleanup afterwards :)

Comment: Thanx for the brilliant idea of window shared service. I'm not sure if using multiple module (app) in the same page is appropriate or not , but the current project im working on is very large project, and it has 2 parallel div's with 2 app modules defined (one is for search filter, and another is for filter result) and the moudles bootstrapped, so i had to handle it anyway. Shared service betwwn controllers of same module is not the case here.
Im confused between app and module now after I read you, can you elaborate the difference between modules and app in angularjs.

Comment: Now I've made a simple change to your jsbin to fit my need http://jsbin.com/paricu/11/edit?html,js,output
Can you please check why the watch is not working here.

Comment: Hm. It does seem like the data gets lost somewhere along the way between $window and $scope. Not sure as to why that is, but like I said - this is just a PoC. I'll edit my answer to further explain the difference between 2x Modules, and 2x Apps.

Comment: [Proof of concept (PoC)](http://www.techopedia.com/definition/4066/proof-of-concept-poc)